# PHP - Edit and Build File

Tags: php, compiler-construction, build

Okay, ive defiantly seen this before back when Google used to have their "Android App Creator" where you can create a custom app and then an .apk file pops out.

I have a program but it requires users to put some information before they can use it. I was wondering if I can get my programs source and then when the user adds the information and presses enter, it will add the information, compile it, and present the file.

How can i do this with PHP?

Comment: Can PHP compile .apk ? I doubt.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor donno exactly now but might be http://phpforandroid.net/

Comment: an apk file is just a zip, if your info that is user specific resides in the strings files, Manifest  then there should be no reason this couldn't be updated, its only the compiled java *.dex that could be a problem.

Comment: I was using Android as an example. Pretend I want my user to enter certain information and they click "enter". When they click that, the PHP script will add that to missing parts in my source and then compile the program, returning an .exe file.